# Can SoftwareSerial be used in an ESP01

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, esp8266, pins, softwareserial

I am using ESP01 as a microcontroller that retrieves information from Firebase and sends them over serial to an Arduino Uno for other uses. I am not using NODEMcu since it has few analog pins and ESP01 is the only option available for me at this time.

Can the GPIO 0 and GPIO 2 pins available in the ESP01 be used as a serial communication pins when defined with SoftwareSerial library?

I want to keep the serial from the existing TX and RX for debugging and testing.

Comment: EspSoftwareSerial

Comment: Check your other post I answered it there. The ESP01 has 2 serial channels.

Comment: I am also interested in your reply.  Please give a reference to your other post.